# Error message(java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException) when trying to connect oracle database from virtualbox to Java(Eclipse) using JDBC

Tags: java, database, jdbc, virtualbox, stringindexoutofbounds

I am getting this error message "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 25978" when I am trying to run following codes:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class test_conn {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
//          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:22:orcl1", "system", "oracle");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=localhost)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(sid=orcl1)))",
                "system", "oracle");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select * from student";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2));
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

}
```

Can you help me resolve this problem?

Following is full-stacktrace I see on my console:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 
25978
at java.lang.String.checkBounds(String.java:385)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:324)
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.extractData(Packet.java:447)
at oracle.net.ns.RefusePacket.<init>(RefusePacket.java:70)
at 
oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.j
ava:233)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>
(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtensio
n.java:30)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at lecture.test_conn.main(test_conn.java:13)
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace with line numbers; it will give us a better understanding of the context of the exception you're seeing.

Comment: You should use `e.printStacktrace()` instead of `System.out.println(e)`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I full stacktrace that I get right above! thanks!

Comment: @nasukkin I full stacktrace that I get right above! thanks!

Comment: Which version of Oracle do you use, and which version of the driver?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  am currently using ojdbc7.jar for the driver and the oracle version I am using is SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0